# How do I multiply all elements in one collection with all the elements in another collection?

Tags: clojure

Say I have:

```
(def s1 [1 2 3 4 5])
(def s2 [1 2 3 4 5])
```

For every `x` in `s1`, I want to multiply it with every `y` in `s2`.

---

To clarify, I basically want the Cartesian product, so I don't think `map` works here.

Comment: Just for fun, here are a few solutions in other languages.  Erlang (and any other language with list comprehensions): `[X * Y || X <- S1, Y <- S2]`  Ruby (1.8.7+): `s1.product(s2).map {|x,y| x*y}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(for [x1 s1
      x2 s2]
  (* x1 x2))
```

Comment: It's... beautiful. *sheds a tear*

Comment: I'm very new to Clojure, and functional programming in general, even though I know what that does... it still feels awkward and hard to wrap my head around it. Can you describe what's happening there?

Comment: Firstly, you can type `(doc for)` at a Clojure REPL to get a (hopefully) good description of what `for` does; if you find it comes short of your expectations, your experience could help in improving the docstring! Secondly, here's a short summary: `for` takes a binding vector and a single "body" expression. The binding vector comprises names of locals (`x1` and `x2` in the above) and sequence-producing expressions (`s1` and `s2`). The body is evaluated once for each tuple of items in the Cartesian product of the seqs (here each (`x1`, `x2`) in the product of `s1` and `s2`).

Comment: Fortunately, I did read the docs online for the for function, unfortunately it made my brain explode.

Comment: The return value of `for` is a lazy sequence of results of evaluating the body for each of the tuples described above. The tuples can be filtered with `:when` and `:while` conditions and extra bindings can be introduced with `:let` inside the binding vector; see the docstring for details on these. (Also, re: your first comment: quite right, good sir! :-))

Comment: See my answer for the java equivalent.  Hopefully it helps you understand.

Answer (score 4):

While solution using **for** is nicer, here is a **map**-only version if you have troubles understanding **for**:

```
(map #(map (partial * %) s2) s1)
```

**for** above expands to something similar, except it would use another anonymous function instead of **partial**, something like this:

```
(map (fn [x] (map (fn [y] (* x y)) s2)) s1)
```

or, neatly formated:

```
(map
  (fn [x]
    (map
      (fn [y]
        (* x y))
      s2))
  s1)
```

Comment: BTW, to get behavior identical to **for** the first (outer) map should be replaced with mapcat.

Comment: @Blaine See for yourself :-) :
(use 'clojure.pprint)
(set-pprint-dispatch code-dispatch)
(pprint (macroexpand '(for [x1 s1 x2 s2] (* x1 x2))))

Comment: I can't figure out formatting in comment replies but here you go:

`(time (dotimes [_ 1e8] 
  (for [
    x1 (range 100) 
    x2 (range 100)] 
  (* x1 x2))
))`
  
"Elapsed time: 1280.237268 msecs"  
  
`(time (dotimes [_ 1e8] 
  (map #(map (partial * %) (range 100)) (range 100) )
))`
  
"Elapsed time: 1743.519268 msecs"

Answer (score 3):

A simple, visual demonstration of the basic functionality of `for`:

```
user=> (pprint 
         (for [tens (range 10) 
               ones (range 10)]
           [tens ones]))
([0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [0 4]
 [0 5]
 [0 6]
 [0 7]
 [0 8]
 [0 9]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [1 5]
 [1 6]
 [1 7]
 [1 8]
 [1 9]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]
 [2 4]
 [2 5]
 [2 6]
 [2 7]
 [2 8]
 [2 9]
 [3 0]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]
 [3 5]
 [3 6]
 [3 7]
 [3 8]
 [3 9]
 [4 0]
 [4 1]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]
 [4 4]
 [4 5]
 [4 6]
 [4 7]
 [4 8]
 [4 9]
 [5 0]
 [5 1]
 [5 2]
 [5 3]
 [5 4]
 [5 5]
 [5 6]
 [5 7]
 [5 8]
 [5 9]
 [6 0]
 [6 1]
 [6 2]
 [6 3]
 [6 4]
 [6 5]
 [6 6]
 [6 7]
 [6 8]
 [6 9]
 [7 0]
 [7 1]
 [7 2]
 [7 3]
 [7 4]
 [7 5]
 [7 6]
 [7 7]
 [7 8]
 [7 9]
 [8 0]
 [8 1]
 [8 2]
 [8 3]
 [8 4]
 [8 5]
 [8 6]
 [8 7]
 [8 8]
 [8 9]
 [9 0]
 [9 1]
 [9 2]
 [9 3]
 [9 4]
 [9 5]
 [9 6]
 [9 7]
 [9 8]
 [9 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the java 1.5 (or newer) equivalent of Michal's code:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

for(int x1 : s1) {
  for(int x2 : s2) {
    numbers.add(x1 * x2);
  }
}
```

The difference is that `for` loops in java don't return a sequence like they do in clojure, so you need to use a mutable `ArrayList` to construct the result.

Definitely not as pretty as the clojure version, but much better than what you would have had to do in Java 1.4.

Comment: But still..clojure ;)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it can get:

```
(map * '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

will yield:

```
(3 8)
```

Comment: Mmh... not quite what I was looking for. It matches my English description, but I should have said from the start that I was looking for the Cartesian product of two sets. I just didn't know what it was called.

Comment: Oops, indeed, I should have ready the answers more carefully.